# Deleting objects from environment in R

Tags: r, environment-variables

I am reading Hadley's Advanced R. In chapter 8, he says that we can remove an object from an environment by using `rm()`. However, I am still able to see the object after removing it.

Here's my code:

```
e<- new.env()
e$a<-1
e$b<-2
e$.a<-3
e$c<-4
ls(e,all.names = TRUE)

#remove the object c
rm("c",envir = e)
ls(e,all.names = TRUE) #Doesn't exist here

#does the variable exist?
exists("c",envir = e) #Shows TRUE. Why is this?
exists("m",envir = e) #FALSE

ls(e,all.names = TRUE)
ls(e)
```

As we can see above, ideally, I'd have expected `exists("c", envir = e)` to return `FALSE`.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem will also exist if you use "C", "t", "df". All function names in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help(exists)`:

> If `inherits` is `TRUE` and a value is not found for `x` in the specified environment, the enclosing frames of the environment are searched until the name `x` is encountered.

Be careful when naming your variables.  You have a conflict with the base function `c()`.  Since `inherits = TRUE` is the default, the enclosing environments are searched and in this case the base function `c()` is found, which produces the `TRUE` result.  Therefore, to search only the environment `e` and then quit, use `inherits = FALSE`.

```
exists("c", envir = e, inherits = FALSE)
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your problem is that e$c has a NULL value try instead using

```
exists("c", envir = e, inherits = FALSE)
```