# Listing Possible Environment Names for a given object in R

Tags: r, object, environment-variables

I am reading Hadley Wickham's Advanced R - Chapter 8 on Environment.

Recently, I encountered a situation where I accidentally created and deleted an object `c` which also exists in `R_GlobalEnv`. Here's my thread: [Deleting objects from environment in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731820/deleting-objects-from-environment-in-r) So, I thought whether there is any way I can know ALL the environment with which an object is (or could be) attached.

I searched this topic on SO, and came across [How to get environment of a variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583211/how-to-get-environment-of-a-variable-in-r) thread, where one of the experts has created a function that works only for `R_GlobalEnv` and not for every environment.

However, on that thread, the expert says that

> This only checks environments created within `.GlobalEnv.` I'm sure you can work out how to extend it to search across more environments though if you need.

I am wondering how to do this.

Here's my code:

```
rm(list=ls()) 
e<- new.env()
parent.env(e) #Should be Global Env.
environmentName(e) #Shows Blank
```

Here's my modified function from that thread:

```
getEnvMod <- function(x) {
  xobj <- deparse(substitute(x))
  gobjects <- ls(envir=.GlobalEnv)
  envirs <- gobjects[sapply(gobjects, function(x) is.environment(get(x)))]
  envirs <- c('.GlobalEnv', envirs)
  xin <- sapply(envirs, function(e) xobj %in% ls(base::get(x = x,envir = e))) #Modified this line
  envirs[xin] 
}
```

When I run this function using:

```
getEnvMod("a")
```

I get the error message: `Error in as.environment(pos) : no item called "base::get(x = x, envir = e)" on the search list`

I get above message although the object exists.

```
exists("a",envir = e)
[1] TRUE

get(x="a",envir = e)
[1] 1
```

I have two questions:

**Question 1:** why does `environmentName(e)` return `""` ? Shouldn't it return `e`?

**Question 2:** I am unsure how I can *list all environments* that have **a particular** object. I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: For 1), suppose I do `myEnv <- new.env(); ename <- function(e) environmentName(e)`. Should `ename(myEnv)` return `e`?

Comment: @Hong -Thank you. Yes, it must return the environment name. I checked your code, and it returns `""`.